# Making a big object iterable

Tags: java, loops, iterator

I have 50 files, each 100MB in size.

Each file has a class representation in my code, example:

```
public class FileRepresentation
{
    private String path;

    public FileRepresentation(String path)
    {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getPath()
    {
        return this.path;
    }
}
```

For the obvious reasons, I can't have 50 Object, 100MB each in my memory while I loop through it.

I have a class which holds the path for the directory of all the files, and I would like to make this class Iterable, and able to return 1 object at a time, meaning every request from the Iterator (loop), it creates a new object and returns it.

```
public class FilesClass
{
    private String folderPath;

    public FilesClass(String folderPath)
    {
        this.folderPath= folderPath;
    }

    //What I want to achieve:
    public FileRepresentation getNextFile()
    {
        return new FileRepresentation("nextFile");
    }
}
```

I have thought about having a counter and every iteration just creating a new object, but it seems wrong.
How can I achieve it? Is there any better way to do it? Maybe I am mistaken and not all the 50 objects are in the memory while in the loop?

Thanks.

EDIT:
I ended up making my suggested method.

Comment: Why don't you just write a loop containing a try-with-resources block to open a file, use it and close it?

Comment: "I have thought about..." is not a valid reason not to actually try something.

Comment: You could create a collection of paths, iterate through that and inside of the loop do reading and all operations on the file.

Comment: I never said I did not tried it, I said I believe it is wrong, and there is a better way to do that. @MadPhysicist

Comment: There is not even the hint of a legitimate attempt shown here. That's much more eloquent than any protestations to the contrary. Fortunately, you can edit your question to include your attempt and the result, hopefully before your question gets closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using my method of a looper:

```
public class FileRepresentation
{
    private String path;

    public FileRepresentation(String path)
    {
        this.path = path;
    }

    public String getPath()
    {
        return this.path;
    }
}
```

```
public class FilesClass
{

    private List<File> files;

    private int counter;

    public FilesClass(List<File> files)
    {
        this.files = files;
        this.counter = 0;
    }

    public FileRepresentation getNextFile()
    {
        FileRepresentation object = myOwnImplementationToConvertFileToObject(this.files.get(counter++));
        return object;
    }
}
```